# Find extra space / new line after a closing ?> (php tag)

Tags: php, regex, unix, find, grep

So I have a space/new line after a closing `?>` (php tag) that is breaking my application.

How can I find it easily I have 1000 of files and 100000 lines of code in this app.

Ideally im after some regex combined with find grep to run on a unix box.

Comment: I suggest to completely omit the closing tag `?>` at the end of the file.

Comment: A single newline after the closing PHP tag is fine (`?>\n`). It's the second newline that breaks it (`?>\n\n`).

Answer (score 14):

The problem here is normal grep doesn't match multiple lines. So, I would install `pcregrep` and try the following command:

```
pcregrep -rMl '\?>[\s\n]+\z' *
```

This will match all files in the folder and subfolders (the `-r` part) using PCRE multiline match (the `-M` part), and only list their filenames (the `-l` part).

As for the pattern, well that matches `?>` followed by 1 or more whitespace or newline characters, followed by the end of the file `\z`. I found though, when I ran this on my folder, many of the PHP files do in fact end with a single newline. So you can update that regex to be `'\?>[\s\n]+\n\z'` to match files with whitespace over and above the single `\n` character terminator.

Lastly, you can always use `od -c filename` to print unambiguous representation of the file if you need to check its exact character sequence ending.

Comment: I had a problem where a PHP file was outputting a single new line while downloading a MS Word file (which corrupts the file). I used this variation of Dave's regex to find it: `pcregrep -rMl '\?>\n\n\z' *`

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with regular grep

```
grep -Pz '\?>[\s]+$' -Rl
```

Will search for all files starting from the current directory and list all that have a `?>` followed by white space *at the end of the file*.

- `-P` Interpret the pattern as a Perl-compatible regular expression (PCRE).
- `-z` Treats the input file as one long line - this is in part what makes it work
- `[\s]+` matches at least one white space - including newlines

If you want to match PHP files only:

```
find -name '*.php' | xargs grep -Pz '\?>[\s]+$' -l
```

To search for white space at the beginning of the file before

```
find -name '*.php' | xargs grep -Pz '^[\s]+<\?' -l
```

Answer (score 1):

use perl;

```
perl -0777 -i -pe 's/\s*$//s' *.php
```

- -0777 will slurp he whole file (-0 will be ok too)
- -i - inplace editing, so the file will be replaces with the result
- -p print lines
- -e perl expression

s/\s*$//s - treat all lines as a single line and substitute any space at the end to nothing

Comment: Nice solution though I think you still want the file to end with *one* newline ('s/\s*$/\n/s').

Answer (score 0):

This works on my box:

```
for i in `find . -name "*.php"`; do (echo -n "$i: "; tail -c 3 $i) | grep -v "[?]>"; done
```

The idea is that you take just the last 3 characters with tail, then discard the files where those are '?', '>' and newline. If there's a space or another newline, you won't get the '?' character..

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e :a -e '/^[ \n]*$/{$d;N;ba' -e '}' -e '$ s/\([^ ]\)*?>[ ]*/\1?>/' file.php > new_file.php
```

to be executed for each file not completely tested..

remember to work on a temporary file and after the sed operation copy the new file on the original one..

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

```
<\?php | \?>
```

If you need to use in in a sublime-settings file or something like that which doesn't like forward slashes, you might have to add an extra slash for each of them like so...

> <\\?php | \\?>

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to find white spaces before php files

```
find -name '*.php' | xargs grep -Pz '\?>[\s]+$' -l
```

Answer (score -1):

`grep '?> ' *.php`? Of course, it may not be a space and could be a linebreak or a tab, so you may want to try other characters.

Comment: This will find every closing tag with white space after it ie in `?> <div class = "blah"><?php echo $blah;?></div><?php echo $blah2; ?> `, the first closing tag would be found.   I really just need the ones at the end of the document with something between the closing tag and the end of the file.  Something like `?>*EOF`

Comment: shotgun approach: `find . -type f -name \*php -exec tail -1 {}|grep '?> ' \;` or something similar.

Answer (score -3):

Using notepad++ you can replace easily all documents at the same time, drap and drop that folder of files and press CTRL + R, also you can use Regex

Comment: Yes, loading 1000+ files into notepad sounds like a good idea :-) (irony)