# Find whitespace-injecting PHP files

Tags: php, regex, bash, grep

Whitespace in PHP files is sometimes problematic, so I'm trying to find files which meet common problematic criteria. I'm trying to find all files recursively which have one or both of these conditions:

1) Does not begin with a `<` or `#` character.

**and/or**

2) Does not end in a `>` character, unless it does end in a close brace which is followed by any amount of newlines.

I think that the first condition would be: `$[^<#]`

I think that the second condition would be: `[ [^>^] | [}\n*^]]`

However, note that in my naive regexes `$` and `^` represent the start and end of the file, not of any line in the file. And even with those, assuming that they were correct, how would I combine them? Like so?

```
[$[^<#]] | [[ [^>^] | [}\n*^]]]
```

Then, putting them in grep:

```
grep -r [$[^<#]] | [[ [^>^] | [}\n*^]]] *
```

Obviously, this is Not Working (tm). Can someone teach me how to correct the mistakes? Thanks.

This is a good file:

```
<?php

?>
```

So is this:

```
<?php
function someFunc(){
}


‏
```

And this is good too:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
?>
```

Leading HTML is fine:

```
<html>
<?php
echo '</html>';
?>
```

Trailing HTML is fine too:

```
<?php
echo '<html>';
?>
</html>
```

This is bad (leading newline):

```
‏
<?php

?>
```

This is bad too (leading space):

```
‏ <?php

?>
```

This is bad as well (trailing newline):

```
<?php

?>
‏
```

Comment: One of the easiest ways to avoid this problem is to NOT include a closing `?>` at the end of files.  This is valid PHP, and is included in many mainstream PHP coding standards, including the PEAR coding standard.  Ending files with `?>` is asking for trouble.

Comment: An idea you might consider: turn on output buffering, `include()` the file, and see if the output it generates when you include it has leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: Thank you Frank. However, files ending in `?>` are valid PHP files, don't trigger the bug, and are very common. I'm not going to argue with other devs on the subject and change their coding style, I just want to automate the process of finding problematic files for me.

Comment: You can use [`phptags --warn *.php`](http://fossil.include-once.org/phptags/index) for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find extra space / new line after a closing ?> (php tag)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126554/find-extra-space-new-line-after-a-closing-php-tag)

Comment: two things: you have to use `-E` option to grep (or egrep) to turn on advance regexp.
Second one: `^` is for the beginning and `$` for then ending of a line, not the opposite.

Comment: @mario: That question certainly is a subcase of this question, but only addresses half the issue. Thanks, though, there is some good info in there that I will pick through.

Answer (score 2):

Tossed up an expression real quick that I think does what you want. It's pretty late here and for some reason I'm on stackoverflow. Regardless, I hope I got your request right.

Try this regular expression `/\A(?:\s+.*>|[^<#].*>\s*|<.*>\s+)\Z/s`. Explained here: http://regex101.com/r/cT7eY5

I hope this help. If I misunderstood you in any way, please clarify and I will try to adjust the expression.

Comment: Thank. It does need a lot of work but this is getting me in the right direction I think. Its late here too!

Comment: I had forgotten the `s`-flag which is necessary for this expression to work. If you were not using it before, make sure you do now.

Comment: Thank you Lindrian. Getting back to this, It doesn't seem to me that `\A` matches the beginning of a file in my version of grep (2.9 on a Debian-derived distro). Does `\A` actually match the beginning of a file on your system? Which system? Thanks.

Comment: It seems that `grep -rE "/\A(?:\s+.*>|[^<#].*>\s*|<.*>\s+)\Z/s"` hangs. Am I running the regex wrong?