# Magento API Error: XML declaration allowed only at the start

Tags: php, xml, api, magento, soap

I'm trying to access Magento's core API. When I try to access the url http://magentohost/index.php/api/soap/wsdl=1 I get the error

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

I have installed xmlrpc, soap, and other extensions that is said to be required but still no luck.

Other magento instances in my host shows

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
```

plus a block of XML codes below it.

It's said that I may have white spaces on my XML document but I have no idea what XML document I should modify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have whitespace in some php/phtml file/s before the starting <?php or at the end of the file, after the closing ?>.

An xml with a precedeing whitespace is invalid and will give an error like yours.

Check the following links for further explanation:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92139/space-added-before-every-magento-page-content

[Find whitespace-injecting PHP files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415675/find-whitespace-injecting-php-files)