# pcregrep for finding all files with extra space before php opening tag

Tags: php, regex, unix, grep, find

I have a working command line code using pcregrep for finding all PHP with space after closing tag:

```
pcregrep -rMl '\?>[\s\n]+\z' *
```

I get that here: [Find extra space / new line after a closing ?> (php tag)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126554/find-extra-space-new-line-after-a-closing-php-tag)

Now I want to know what is the equivalent command above finding all spaces before PHP opening tag at the beginning of the PHP file:

```
[SPACE HERE]<?php
```

If you know how to do this, please share thanks.

Comment: Thanks Falsetru, I think it's not the correct one. I just tried it now but it returns files with no spaces before PHP opening tag.

Comment: Can you provide a sample string/testcase ?

Comment: `[\s\n]+<\?php`, I forgot escaping `?`.

Comment: @falsetrue: yes I have tried that one and it does not work..@NeverHopeless, I have updated my question, I only need to match it with space or spaces before the opening tag at the beginning of the PHP file. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this pattern:

```
([\s\n]+)(?=\<\?php)
```

You should try escaping `<` and `?` since they have a specific meaning in regex. I prefer look around here since no need to consume the upcoming stuff and grouped the results that comes before PHP tag.

You can skip `\n` from the above pattern.

#### [Live demo](http://rubular.com/r/jfPxcvJndw)

Comment: Thanks works great..though it returns true for files containing spaces after the first php opening (example for second PHP opening tag with spaces before them)..nevertheless I have little files to search which is OK with me.