# Easy way to find file with ?> at the end?

Tags: php

I am getting this error:

```
Getting Warning - Cannot modify header information
```

I'm 99% sure it's because of a file ending with ?> and then some white space after that.

My problem is, I have looked at 15 possible files, but there are hundreds more to check. Is there an easy linux command to find the files ending with ?> and some whitespace after it? Or perhaps is there another way you guys solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find extra space / new line after a closing ?> (php tag)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126554/find-extra-space-new-line-after-a-closing-php-tag)

Comment: You can open project with Sublime text 3 and use global project find (cntr + shift + F) to globally search `?> `.

Comment: @Troyer, that will find every single case of it, which is going to be far more than the actual guilty one's

Comment: This is for sure a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126554/find-extra-space-new-line-after-a-closing-php-tag

Comment: This isn’t the full original PHP error message - those contains the info where the first output happened (file & line) as well. (If your system is hiding the full error message from you, then I would go look where to turn that off temporarily.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing a [EOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) problem.

The whitespace at the end of the file its breaking your program, you need to find all the end of file occurrences with `?>(whitespace)`.

You can use a regex expression with a project finder tool, the regex would be: `(?> )\z`.

The `\z` regex condition will look for `?>(whitespace)` only in the EOF.

I recommend you Sublime text 3 because you can apply regex doing a search and replace, there's a Sublime text [find & replace examples](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html) if you want to learn how to.